# Get each input value contained in an array

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a problem getting email input value from forms. 
I'm using WordPress with Contact Form 7 plugin and I have 3 times the same form on the same page `(the form ID is changing according to CF7 standards)` to push users to register.

Thing is that I need to get the value when the form is submitted and store the value in localStorage but actually, I can only get values by pressing which input I want to get the value from because it's considered as an array.

How can I do to get the value whenever the user clicks on submit please, whatever the input and whatever the form?

I think I need to do a loop and tried different approaches but didn't find the solution yet.

Many thanks for any help or advice.

Actually my JS code is this one on submit event:

```
document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function (event) {
    if ('3819' == event.detail.contactFormId || '3904' == event.detail.contactFormId || '4083' == event.detail.contactFormId || '5154' == event.detail.contactFormId) {
        if (event.detail.status != "validation_failed") {
            var cfremail = $('input[name="email-driver"]')[2].value;
            var cfrEmailValue = localStorage.setItem('cfrEmail', cfremail);
            check_email_user(event.detail.inputs.value, 'berline', event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show that page or make a fiddle

Comment: @NegiRox here is the page https://www.marcel.cab/devenir-chauffeur-vtc/
It will be clearer for you to understand. One more thing, the 3rd form is "hidden" and in a template file where we put all our modals. 
If you enter an email address in the first form you see on the page and submit, value of input will be save in localStorage and you will have your email directly filled on the next page in the mail input.  
For the other forms it didn't work but that's my problem actually :)